# The power transmitted by a sinusoidal wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, waves

The power transmitted by a sinusoidal wave on a stretched string is
$$P = \frac{1}{2}\mu v\omega^{2}A^{2}.$$
Is the power proportional to the square or the cube of frequency? 
$$v=\lambda f  \:\:\:  ,  \:\:\:\: \omega^{2}=(2\pi f)^{2}$$
$$ \Rightarrow \:\: P = 2\pi^{2}\mu\lambda A^{2}f^{3} $$
Why can't I consider the power proportional to the cube of frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a resistor: Power =$I^{2}R$, but also Power =$\frac{V^2}{R}$. So is power proportional to $R$ or to $R^{-1}$ ? It depends what you keep constant: $I$ or $V$!

It's much the same in the case you're considering. If we're taking $v$ as a constant (which is pretty accurate for a given string under constant tension, as long as the wavelength isn't very short or the amplitude very large), then power is proportional to $f^2$.

The second version you consider would, with $\lambda$ held constant, give power proportional to $f^3$. But holding $\lambda$ constant while varying $f$ would be really weird as it would involve varying the string tension (in order to have different values of $v$ while leaving $\mu$ unchanged)!